# Any new Word 2021 feature I might have missed

Tags: microsoft-word

I just upgraded from Word 2013 to Word 2021. While I am mostly happy with the upgrade, I'm struggling to find any new features that impress me. I don’t use any fancy formatting or need collaborative features. I would have hoped since I even skipped two upgrades in between, I would have been able to edit the right-click menu or change Ribbon icons by now.

Have I missed some basic new ease of use new feature?

So far my favorite new feature is the title bar is blue which makes the entire program feel friendlier. My 66-year-old eyes are not thrilled with the flatter thinner icons.

Comment: Features are documented. Us knowing what will interest you is kinda odd: we don't know you or what you know or need or use.

Answer (score 1):

Word2021 includes new stock media from the Office Premium Creative Content collection, and new Draw tab additions such as Point Eraser, Ruler, and Lasso.
For more information, please refer to this link: [What's new in Word 2021 for Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-s-new-in-word-2021-for-windows-8f0b9117-8cf4-4677-8cd5-d848dd0e1ac9)

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. If the link dies or changes its contents, the answer will become useless. Quote the relevant parts in your answer. Make sure to mark them as a quote and provide the link as a source.

Answer (score 0):

Word 2021 have new feaure to list.

1. Co-author documents. (Have feature in Word / Excel / PowerPoint)
2. Better collaboration with modern comments. (Have feature in Word / Excel / PowerPoint)
3. Know who's in your document. (Have feature in Word / Excel / PowerPoint)
4. Visual refresh. (Have feature in all Office app)
5. Improve comprehension with Line Focus.
6. See what’s new in stock media. (Have feature in Word / Excel / PowerPoint / Outlook / Visio)
7. Find what you need with Microsoft Search. (Have feature in Word / Excel / PowerPoint / Outlook / OneNote)
8. Increase the reach of your content. (Have feature in Word / Excel / PowerPoint)
9. Performance improvements. (Have feature in Word / Excel / PowerPoint / Outlook)
10. Updated Draw tab. (Have feature in Word / Excel / PowerPoint)
11. Save your changes as they happen. (Have feature in Word / Excel / PowerPoint)
12. Support for OpenDocument format (ODF) 1.3 version. (Have feature in Word / Excel / PowerPoint)
13. Try the Sketched style outline. (Have feature in Word / Excel / PowerPoint)
14. Pick the perfect color. (Have feature in all Office app)
15. Reduce eye strain with Dark Mode.

Credit link [one](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-s-new-in-office-2021-43848c29-665d-4b1b-bc12-acd2bfb3910a) and [two](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-s-new-in-word-2021-for-windows-8f0b9117-8cf4-4677-8cd5-d848dd0e1ac9).